# Linker Error 2019 C++,VS2008

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am using VS 2008.
I have Library 5 Lib file

A.lib
B.lib
C.lib
D.lib
E.lib

A.Lib Include all the header file of B,C,D,E

Now I am trying to Use A.
Lib in MFC application Sample.

I Have Included all the lib file in Sample App and All the setting like code generation,character set is same for all the project. I have made MFC application to use static lib.
I am getting Linker error 2019 in Lib A.lib(A.obj) error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall _Tables::reclaimIfPossible(....

Here reclaimIfPossible function is implemented in b.lib

Comment: Is there anything in a.lib named (.obj) which references an external symbol named `public` or maybe `void`?  (It looks like the question is chopped off.)

Comment: @Chris_vr:  So, is there a definition (not declaration) somewhere for that symbol?

Comment: @wallyk Yes a.lib reference reclaimIfPossible which there in b.lib.

Comment: @wallyk since I am adding b.lib which contain the function reclaimIfPossible.Isn't that sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must link to all libraries.

Only linking to A.lib will only give you symbols for methods defined in A.lib. If anything in A.lib uses anything from the other libraries, you'll get unresolved external symbol.

Comment: I am adding all the library in MFC application

Comment: MFC App Link all Lib A,B,C,D,E.  In A.lib Project I have added Include path of All the .h file used in the B,C,D,E.But MFC application I have Not Included the Path for .h file used in B,C,D,E.Becuz A.lib is already doing that